# How can I switch back to "old" login page?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I have two different versions of the spring-boot-admin (2.1.5 and 2.3.1). The appearance of the login page is of course always a matter of taste, but I found the old one, as in 2.1.5 (image 1)

[image: Image1]

in comparison (image 2)

[image: Image2]

simply more appealing. How can I integrate the old login page? Is there a template for this?

Answer (score 0):

First login is rendered by spring-boot-admin and second one is default spring security
login form.

I suppose that you have restricted access to `/login` endpoint.
Adding
`.antMatchers(this.adminServer.path("/login")).permitAll()` in `authorizeRequests()`
security configuration should fix it.